# How do I use pins and spacings to keep my interface centered on screen unrelated to screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a button on top, with "EasyPost" logo, a label under it, and four buttons.

On 3.5 inch display everything looks great, but I can't keep the thing in control on 4 inch display. After some playing with constrains and pins I just removed all custom pins and left default settings.

The two big buttons on bottom drag below, and I want everything to be the same.
All I want is to have all of this shift a little down on 4 inch display, so whitespace on top of screen and whitespace on bottom screen was the same.

Here are some screenshots:

1. Non retina - everything is great - http://i45.tinypic.com/2d7ahxk.jpg
2. 3.5 inch retina - all good - http://i46.tinypic.com/2jwrw1.png
3. 4 inch retina - bad times - http://i45.tinypic.com/35bgfww.png

I tried pinning buttons together, but then the low buttons would stretch. And I can't remove bottom space to superview. What can be done?

Sometimes randomly this happens, after I try to clear up the restrains
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Springs and struts are a pain to work with in "compositions" like the one you're trying to do. My idea would be putting your four buttons inside a container UIView and then positioning the entire container in the center by removing all springs and struts. Quick and painless solution for the cost of an UIView :)

Comment: After I embedded these in another view I still get same results, when resizing the superview that subview also gets resized, and problems arise.

Comment: You would have to remove all springs and struts from the container view (so it doesn't get resized and keeps centered if the window is bigger), and set the springs and struts of the subviews so they are "fixed" inside the container (usually done by setting the top and left struts only). Also, the container view must have the same width/height as you entire set of buttons (i.e. if each button is 50x50, your container view would be 100x100). I built a small project to demonstrate this approach - check it out: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42774/springsandstruts.zip